# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when using SQL variables in a query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mariadb, heidisql

This is my SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (UniqueID, SomeData, SomeNumber)
VALUES (@unique_id + 1, 'some value', '4234435435')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
OtherNum = OtherNum + 1, SomeNumber = '999';
SELECT @unique_id := MAX(UniqueID) FROM SomeTable;
```

I use MariaDB. And I use HeidiSQL to manage databases, execute queries etc. In HeidiSQL my query works fine, but when I try to execute it in Java I get SQLSyntaxErrorException. Here is how I do it:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/somedb?user=root&password=password");
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO SomeTable (UniqueID, SomeData, SomeNumber)\n"
           + "VALUES (@unique_id + 1, 'some value', '4234435435')\n"
           + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n"
           + "OtherNum = OtherNum + 1, SomeNumber = '999';\n"
           + "SELECT @unique_id := MAX(UniqueID) FROM SomeTable;");
```

In the exception info I see it's caused by "SELECT @unique_id := MAX(UniqueID) FROM SomeTable;" line. Here is the full exception info:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:29) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @unique_id := MAX(UniqueID) FROM SomeTable' at line 4

Why does this happen and how to make it work?

Comment: How do you pass the parameter @unique_id? Is it working if you pass it direct like VALUES (123456789, 'some value', 4234435435)? And i would also try without the lineendings \n

Comment: You can't execute multiple statements in one execute by default (because technically JDBC doesn't allow it). You need to specify connection property `allowMultiQueries=true`, see [Optional URL parameters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/#optional-url-parameters)

Comment: But seriously, for this you should use an auto increment column and use the JDBC `getGeneratedKeys` facility instead, your current code is susceptible to race conditions and might lead to duplicate keys.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you, I added `allowMultiQueries=true` and everything worked. About autoincrement - it didn't work well for me. What I need to do is to add 'some value' to the SomeData field in case if the table doesn't contain SomeData = 'some value'. If the table contains it, I need to increment OtherNum that corresponds to 'some value'. When I used autoincrement every time I updated OtherNum, UniqueID was incrementing. So, later when I inserted other value to SomeData I had gaps in UniqueID. I don't think I would have duplicate keys because SomeData is an unique key as well as UniqueID